# Como posso centralizar meu menu de dropdown?

Tags: html5, css3

Olá. Estou cursando o primeiro mês de um curso técnico e estou com o trabalho de criar um site utilizando técnicas de HTML5 e CSS3 que aprendemos em sala e inovações seriam bem vindas.
Eu procurei muito sobre menus com dropdown e uma pessoa no facebook me ajudou aplicar o dropdown no meu site, porém o menu está todo alinhado para a esquerda e já tentei reescrever e editar o máximo possível, mas não houve exito. Como posso estar resolvendo?

Aqui está o projeto http://codepen.io/w1l14n/pen/dprrVa (desculpem mas como o usuário tentou acrescentar o dropdown num menu já pronto, resultou nisso kk)

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é facilmente resolvido usando `display: flex` na sua classe `menu`, por exemplo;

```
.menu {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-display: flex;
  -moz-display: flex;
  -o-display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

O que mais importa para você é o  `display: flex`, as linhas onde estao escritas `-moz-, -o- e -webkit-` servem para termos certeza de que isso vai funcionar em todos os navegadores.

Aqui estão alguns links para te ajudar no aprendizado do flexbox.

[Css trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Awesome BR](http://awesome-br.com/#/), este link contem conteudo para diversos assuntos, inclusive css, note que dentro da categoria CSS você também pode encontrar um jogo super legal para ajudar no aprendizado de flexbox. [Flexbox Froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/#pt-br)

Comment: Olá Rafael. Isso realmente resolveu meu problema. Estou a procura da resposta a dias e nunca consigo chegar num resultado correto. muitíssimo obrigado e me desculpa pelo incomodo que possa ter gerado.

Tenha um ótimo dia

Comment: @WilianSilva incomodo nenhum amigo, estamos aqui para ajudar mesmo.